# R: create data table from list of lists/list of numerics

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

With `data frames` generating a data frame from a list of lists is quite straightforward. For example:

```
 hists = lapply(sort(unique(country_hours$country)), function(x) get_hist_per_country(x, country_hours ) )
hists_df = data.frame(hists)
```

This gets me a dataframe with number of columns equal to `length(hists)`

However, if I try to make a `data table`:

```
hists_dt = data.table(hists)
```

and

```
hists_dt = data.table(lapply(hists, cbind))
```

both produce a single column data table. How do I generate a data table from a list of lists?

Comment: Try `do.call(data.table,lapply(1:3, function(x) sample(10)))`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need a data table? Isn't the data frame enough?

Comment: Alternately, you can just make your data.frame and then use `setDT` on it to make it a data.table by reference.

Comment: `as.data.table(lapply(hist, unlist))` or `setDT(lapply(hist, unlist))`

Comment: @TejaK data.tables are well established at being faster and more memory efficient than dataframes for many, if not most, operations.